# Problem on using GPU and Tensorflow: "no kernel image is available for execution on the device"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I've got this message:

> F .\tensorflow/core/kernels/random_op_gpu.h:232] Non‑OK‑status:
> GpuLaunchKernel(FillPhiloxRandomKernelLaunch, num_blocks, block_size,
> 0, d.stream(), gen, data, size, dist) status: Internal: no kernel
> image is available for execution on the device

while launching my YOLO detecting algorithm using the GPU of my laptop. (If I disable the GPU research by TensorFlow, everything works fine but slow)

I thought it was due to an error on CUDA/cuDNN installing procedure but I've performed the checks and all seems to be fine.

Can someone help me to figure out what's going on?

I'm using:

- Windows 10
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce 940MX
- CUDA 10.1
- cuDNN 7.6
- Python 3.7
- Tensorflow 2.3.1
- keras 2.4

Comment: Your GPU is of compute capability 5.0.  TF2.3 appears to have [dropped support](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41892) for it.  You might have better luck with TF2.2

Comment: I solved the problem building TensorFlow from source.
(https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows)